# vagrant up hostonly issue --host-only-net9=HostOnly | Windows 10

Tags: laravel, windows, vagrant, homestead, vbox

When I want to excecute vagrant up command, the following issue is shown:

```
Bringing machine 'homestead' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' version '12.2.0' is up to date...
==> homestead: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> homestead: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> homestead: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    homestead: Adapter 1: nat
    homestead: Adapter 2: intnet
==> homestead: Forwarding ports...
    homestead: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> homestead: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
A customization command failed:

["modifyvm", :id, "--nic9", "hostonlynet", "--host-only-net9=HostOnly"]

The following error was experienced:

#<Vagrant::Errors::VBoxManageError: There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["modifyvm", "4474afc8-04d0-4ca3-b39f-748e3ab46b5f", "--nic9", "hostonlynet", "--host-only-net9=HostOnly"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Invalid NIC number 9
Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 6.1.40
(C) 2005-2022 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.

Usage:

VBoxManage modifyvm         <uuid|vmname>
                            [--name <name>]
                            [--groups <group>, ...]
                            [--description <desc>]

(.....A LOT OF COMMANDS OF MODIFYVM....)

                            [--defaultfrontend default|<name>]

VBoxManage.exe: error: Unknown option: --host-only-net9=HostOnly
>

Please fix this customization and try again.
```

---

Hello, I have this issue and I couldn't solve it neither find a solution on the web.

I don't know what else to try, that's why I'm here.
I've tried these same following steps in 3 different pc's with intel and amd with Windows 10 and It didn't work.

I think there's a setting that I still don't know I have to set about Hosts, ports and VirtualBox, because It doesn't matter what Adapter Ports do I configure to homestead, when I excecute Vagrant Up they are reseted and then the issue is shown on bash.

This is what I've done:

1. I've installed virtual Box 6.1.4 version.
2. I've installed Vagrant 2.3.2
3. Added C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox  to enviroment variables

I excecuted the following commands on bash:

4. vagrant box add laravel/homestead

   - Option 2) VirtualBox
5. git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead
6. cd Homestead
7. bash init.sh
8. ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "email"
9. Created code folder on the user folder
10. vagrant up

Please help!

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Vagrant is specifically off topic. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on

Answer (score 4):

You miss one step:

6. ```
   cd ~/Homestead
   ```

after you need to:

7. ```
   git checkout release
   ```

after you can run:

8. ```
   bash init.sh
   ```

... or

```
vagrant up --provision
```

[image]

I had the same issue today, this solved the problem.

Comment: It doesn't work for me

Answer (score 4):

Solved an issue by reverting changes of [this commit](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/commit/4b258ed7aeaed89f151b15b3cdcef92ca14725db).

Idk why this was added. Laravel homestead installation instructions says it has support of VirtualBox 6.1.x but commit message says "Updating HostOnly adapter for VirtualBox 7"